# VirtualBox (Linux) not able to ping Windows' Hamachi network users

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn, hamachi

**Scenario:**
I have a Windows host, with Hamachi installed and it is connected to a Network with N clients;
I also have a Kali Linux running in a VirtualBox setup;
How can I make my Kali Linux ping the clients that my Windows host can ping? In other words I want my VM to ping everything my host pings.

**Things I've tried:**
**1)** Setting the first network adapter as NAT and the second as bridged LogMeIn adapter;

**2)** Installing Hamachi on the VM and connecting to the same Network as my Host (curious fact: I can see the host is online but cannot ping it; but the host can ping the VM with Hamachi IPv4);

**3)** Setting the first network adapter as bridged ethernet and the second as bridged LogMeIn adapter;

**4)** Setting eth0 as NAT, eth1 as the host's Hamachi adapter Bridged and, inside Kali, making a bridge br0 between those two.
I ran out of ideas and have little networking knowledge.

EDIT:
Ok, so I finally made my VM ping my host hamachi IP help from this [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37122/virtualbox-two-network-interfaces-nat-and-host-only-ones-in-a-debian-guest-on).

I just had to add the following lines to my `/etc/network/interface`:

```
# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Also, I have eth0 as NAT and eth1 as the host's Hamachi Adapter in Bridge Mode.
I had to take down the Linux's Hamachi interface `ham0`, so installing Hamachi in the VM is useless.
But still I cannot ping the Hamachi IPs my host knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally made it out using help from this [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37122/virtualbox-two-network-interfaces-nat-and-host-only-ones-in-a-debian-guest-on).

I just had to add the following lines to my `/etc/network/interface`:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Also, I have eth0 as NAT and eth1 as the host's Hamachi Adapter in Bridge Mode.
Both of the adapters stay in unamanaged mode.
With this I was able to ping my Hamachi "co-networkers" from both my Kali VM and the Host (Windows).